# run binary file with qeum on my M1 Mabook?

Tags: nasm, qemu, apple-m1, macos-monterey

My qemu version is 6.2.0, and I did all of this in my M1 MacBook(Monterey 12.1)
Before the problem, I can get right results about the tutorial(https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/01-bootsector-barebones).
After I input the command of "qemu-system-aarch64 -S -drive file=boot_sect_simple.bin,format=raw -machine virt-5.2"
There is nothing in my qemu console.
The picture is as below.
[image: my qemu console]
I did not get the message of "Booting from Hard Disk..." in chapter 01.
Is there any solutions to let me get message:"Booting from Hard Disk..." like the chaoter 01?

Answer (score 0):

I am so confused.But it is works by using qemu-system-x86_64 instead.

Comment: You're trying to run an x86 guest -- so you must use qemu-system-x86_64. qemu-system-aarch64 is for running Arm guests!